# rJava and tabulizer not working on mac Catalina

Tags: r, rjava, tabulizer

I have tried everything to try and get rJava to load but I have failed. Any suggestions as to how I can solve this problem? When I run library(rJava) in R (not R studio) it seems to load.

> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/")
>   library(tabulizer)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tabulizer’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tabulizerjars', details:
>     call: NULL
>     error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: if you have admin rights in your computer / machine, try checking this out? https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately it gave me the following error: